# Interpretation of watts per square meter for intensity of radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

The energy that an electromagnetic field can deliver to a system is proportional to the square of the field. However, we use the terminology watts per meter square to represent the amount of energy going past to represent the intensity of EM waves. How do you give a physical meaning to the 'amount of energy that the field **carries past us per second**' if you are only given the amount of energy that an EM field can **deliver to a system**? Why is it necessary to adopt watts per meter square for intensity, *whereas I believe the energy that can be delivered to a system is perfectly fine for defining intensity*

Comment: Because energy per second is Watts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JonCuster  What is meant in my question is that why can't we just use the maximum energy that can be delivered to a system to define intensity? Why is it necessary to use watts per meter square instead for the definition

Comment: @ZixhNode What's the maximum energy a solar panel can collect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a solar panel in sunlight for a second, capture some energy. Now put it in sunlight for two seconds: you'll double the energy captured. Now double the area of the panel: once again, you'll double the energy. So the energy is $E=\epsilon AtI$ where $A$ is the panel area, $t$ is the exposure time, $I$ is the light intensity, and $\epsilon$ is the efficiency (typically ~0.2 for a silIcon solar panel). So, by dimensional analysis, if $E$ is joules, $A$ is square meters, and $t$ is seconds, $I$ must be $J/s/m^2$ or $W/m^2$ (same thing).